# Python 3.9 При заполнении двумерного массива кортежами, в какой-то момент вместо записи в одну ячейку, происходит заполнение многих

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, матрицы

Вопрос по глюку заполнения двумерной матрицы  в Python 3.9.

В двух вложенных циклах, пэлементно заполняю двумерный массив. В какой-то момент, происходит необъяснимая запись сразу во всё продолжение ряда (множество ячеек).
Вот распечатка массива, сначала всё работает правильно, каждый раз в одной ячейке появляется новый элемент. А затем приходит глюк.

```
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2041, 2042), (2043, 2044), (2045, 2046), (2047, 2048), (2049, 2050)]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2051, 2052), (2053, 2054), (2055, 2056), (2057, 2058), None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Записался элемент (2057, 2058)

```
    --- [None, None, None, None, None, (2041, 2042), (2043, 2044), (2045, 2046), (2047, 2048), (2049, 2050)]
    --- [None, None, None, None, None, (2051, 2052), (2053, 2054), (2055, 2056), (2057, 2058), (2059, 2060)]
    --- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
    --- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
    --- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
    --- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
    --- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
    --- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
    --- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
    --- [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

Записался элемент (2059, 2060)

--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2041, 2042), (2043, 2044), (2045, 2046), (2047, 2048), (2049, 2050)]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2051, 2052), (2053, 2054), (2055, 2056), (2057, 2058), (2059, 2060)]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), None, None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), None, None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), None, None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), None, None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), None, None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), None, None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), None, None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), None, None, None, None]
```

Вот оно! (2061, 2062) расползся вниз по непонятным причинам!!!
И так продолжается с каждой дальнейшей итерацией

```
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2041, 2042), (2043, 2044), (2045, 2046), (2047, 2048), (2049, 2050)]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2051, 2052), (2053, 2054), (2055, 2056), (2057, 2058), (2059, 2060)]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), (2063, 2064), None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), (2063, 2064), None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), (2063, 2064), None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), (2063, 2064), None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), (2063, 2064), None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), (2063, 2064), None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), (2063, 2064), None, None, None]
--- [None, None, None, None, None, (2061, 2062), (2063, 2064), None, None, None]
```

Вот кусок кода, где появляется глюк:

```
def draw_cubes():
    # добавляю фигуру в стэк кубиков
    global figure
    print("draw cubes start")
    for line in CUBES:
        print("Fom the beginning:", line)
    for i, line in enumerate(figure.figure_map):
        for j, element in enumerate(line):
            if figure.figure_map[i][j] == '1':
                y = figure.y - i
                x = figure.x + j
                
                # Именно это присвоение ГЛЮЧИТ, но не сразу
                CUBES[-y-1][x] = draw_cube_element(y, x, "green", "yellow")
                
                #Распечатываю массив для отладки
                for l in CUBES:
                    print("---", l)
```

Подробнее.
Игра Тетрис.
Все кубики хранятся в матрице CUBES соответствующей размеру стакана (10х10) изначально заполненной None в каждой ячейке. Когда в ячейку попадает кубик, туда прописывается Id элемента canvas.
Всё прекрасно работает, но когда Id достигают района 2000+, вдруг, при записи элемента в одну ячейку, он записывается во все оставшиеся ячейки по "y".

Наглядно это видно в консольном выводе:

Для отладки распечатывается массив CUBES при каждом добавлении элемента в ячейку.

Играя в игру с тестовой фигурой 5х4, четырежды расставляя её по краям, на пятый раз, глюк проявляется.
Фигура опускается клавишей "d". Управляется стрелками.

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Весь код:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import random

GLASS_WIDTH = 10
GLASS_HEIGHT = 10
BLOCK_SIZE = 30
START_X = 3
START_Y = 3

CUBES = []
for i in range(GLASS_HEIGHT):
    row = []
    for j in range(GLASS_WIDTH):
        row.append(None)
    CUBES.append(row)

empty_cubes_line = []
for i in range(GLASS_WIDTH):
    empty_cubes_line.append(None)

# разные варианты фигур
'''FIGURE_TYPES = [['10',
                 '10',
                 '11'], ['1'], ['110',
                                '011'], ['111']]'''
# фигура для отладки
FIGURE_TYPES = [['11111',
                 '11111',
                 '11111',
                 '11111']]


def make_figure_choice():
    the_choice = random.randrange(len(FIGURE_TYPES))
    return FIGURE_TYPES[the_choice]


class Figure:
    def __init__(self):
        self.figure_map = make_figure_choice()
        self.x = START_X
        self.y = START_Y
        self.block_list = []

    def rotate_left(self):
        m = len(self.figure_map)
        n = len(self.figure_map[0])
        new_matrix = [[self.figure_map[j][i] for j in range(m)] for i in range(n-1, -1, -1)]
        self.figure_map = new_matrix

    def rotate_right(self):
        m = len(self.figure_map)
        n = len(self.figure_map[0])
        new_matrix = [[self.figure_map[j][i] for j in range(m-1, -1, -1)] for i in range(n)]
        self.figure_map = new_matrix

    def move_left(self):
        self.x = self.x - 1

    def move_right(self):
        self.x = self.x + 1

    def move_down(self):
        self.y += 1


figure = Figure()


tk = Tk()
tk.title("Тетрис")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=GLASS_WIDTH * BLOCK_SIZE, height=GLASS_HEIGHT * BLOCK_SIZE, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

GAME_ON = True


def draw_figure():
    global GAME_ON
    if check_collision():
        GAME_ON = False

    if len(figure.block_list) >= 1:
        for item in figure.block_list:
            canvas.delete(item[0])
            canvas.delete(item[1])
            figure.block_list = []

    for i, line in enumerate(figure.figure_map):
        for j, element in enumerate(line):
            if figure.figure_map[i][j] == '1':
                y = figure.y - i
                x = figure.x + j

                id1, id2 = draw_cube_element(y, x, 'blue', 'black')

                figure.block_list.append((id1, id2))
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()


def draw_cubes():
    global figure
    
    # добавляю фигуру в стэк кубиков
    for i, line in enumerate(figure.figure_map):
        for j, element in enumerate(line):
            if figure.figure_map[i][j] == '1':
                y = figure.y - i
                x = figure.x + j

# Непонятная ошибка здесь. В какой-то момент он заполняет одинаковыми данными все ячейки линий дальше нужной, вместо одной линии (ячейки)
# причём, с зтого момента он так и пуляет данные во много ячеек, начиная с той линии, где включился глюк
# включается глюк не сразу, а после нескольких правильных итераций
                CUBES[-y-1][x] = draw_cube_element(y, x, "green", "yellow")

                for l in CUBES:
                    print("---", l)
                print(-y-1, "\n")
                
    # удаляю заполненные ряды
    to_redraw = False
    for line in reversed(CUBES):

        to_delete = True
        for element in line:
            if element is None:
                to_delete = False
                break
        if to_delete:
            to_redraw = True
            for element in line:
                delete_cube_element(element)
            CUBES.remove(line)
            CUBES.append(empty_cubes_line)

    # Перерисовываю все кубики (удаляю старые, рисую новые) если было удаление линии
    if to_redraw:
        for i, line in enumerate(reversed(CUBES)):
            for j, item in enumerate(line):
                if item is not None:
                    delete_cube_element(item)

                    id1, id2 = draw_cube_element(i, j, 'red', 'orange')

                    CUBES[-i-1][j] = (id1, id2)
                    print(-i-1, j)
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    tk.update_idletasks()
                    tk.update()

    make_new_figure()


def make_new_figure():
    global GAME_ON
    figure.x = START_X
    figure.y = START_Y
    if check_collision():
        GAME_ON = False
    figure.figure_map = make_figure_choice()
    draw_figure()


def delete_cube_element(element):
    canvas.delete(element[0])
    canvas.delete(element[1])


def draw_cube_element(i, j, fill1, fill2):
    id1 = canvas.create_rectangle(j * BLOCK_SIZE, i * BLOCK_SIZE,
                                  j * BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE, i * BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE,
                                  fill=fill1)
    id2 = canvas.create_rectangle(j * BLOCK_SIZE + 2, i * BLOCK_SIZE + 2,
                                  j * BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE - 2, i * BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE - 2,
                                  fill=fill2)
    return id1, id2


def check_collision():
    for i, line in enumerate(figure.figure_map):
        for j, item in enumerate(line):
            if figure.figure_map[i][j] == '1':
                if figure.x + j >= GLASS_WIDTH or figure.x + j < 0 or figure.y >= GLASS_HEIGHT:
                    return True
                if figure.y - i >0 and CUBES[-figure.y+i-1][figure.x + j] is not None:
                    return True

    return False


def check_borders(movement_type):

    if movement_type == 'Right':
        if check_collision():
            figure.move_left()

    if movement_type == 'Left':
        if check_collision():
            figure.move_right()

    if movement_type == 'Up':
        # Если есть наложение, то двигаю фигуру влево (столько раз сколько длинна фигуры)
        for i in range(len(figure.figure_map[0])-1):
            if check_collision():
                figure.move_left()
        # Если смещение влево не помогло...
        if check_collision():
            # возвращаю фигуру на место
            for i in range(len(figure.figure_map[0]) - 1):
                figure.move_right()
            # Двигаю фигуру вправо, вдруг там свободно
            for i in range(len(figure.figure_map[0])):
                if check_collision():
                    figure.move_right()
            # возвращаю обратно, если не вышло
            if check_collision():
                for i in range(len(figure.figure_map[0])):
                    figure.move_left()
                figure.rotate_right()


    if movement_type == 'Down':
        # Если есть наложение, то двигаю фигуру влево (столько раз сколько длинна фигуры)
        for i in range(len(figure.figure_map[0]) - 1):
            if check_collision():
                figure.move_left()
        # Если смещение влево не помогло...
        if check_collision():
            # возвращаю фигуру на место
            for i in range(len(figure.figure_map[0]) - 1):
                figure.move_right()
            # Двигаю фигуру вправо, вдруг там свободно
            for i in range(len(figure.figure_map[0])):
                if check_collision():
                    figure.move_right()
            # возвращаю обратно, если не вышло
            if check_collision():
                for i in range(len(figure.figure_map[0])):
                    figure.move_left()
                figure.rotate_left()

    if check_collision():
        figure.y = figure.y - 1
        return True

    return False


def new_coordinates(event):
    if event == "no_button":
        movement_type = "d"
        figure.move_down()
    else:
        movement_type = event.keysym
        if movement_type == "Up":
            figure.rotate_left()
        if movement_type == "Down":
            figure.rotate_right()
        if movement_type == "Left":
            figure.move_left()
        if movement_type == "Right":
            figure.move_right()
        if movement_type == "d":
            figure.move_down()

    if check_borders(movement_type):
        draw_cubes()
    else:
        draw_figure()


canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Left>", new_coordinates)
canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Right>", new_coordinates)
canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Up>", new_coordinates)
canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Down>", new_coordinates)
canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-d>", new_coordinates)

'''while GAME_ON:

    draw_figure()
    new_coordinates("no_button")
    #tk.update_idletasks()
    #tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.5)'''

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня сейчас нет возможности детально разбираться в этом большом коде, так что я могу ошибаться.

Но, кажется, дело в следующем:

У вас `empty_cubes_line` - это всегда один и тот же массив, который вы используете много раз. Соответственно, когда вы обновляете элемент массива, он обновляется во всех местах, где используется `empty_cubes_line`.

Попробуйте сделать так:

Строки 18-20 заменить на такую функцию:

```
def empty_cubes_line():
    return [None for _ in range(GLASS_WIDTH)]
```

А в тех местах, где вам понадобится пустая строка, вызывайте эту функцию. Например так:

```
# Просто добавляете пустые скобки к тому, что у вас было
CUBES.append(empty_cubes_line())
```